# How can I set and use alternate icons on touchbar buttons with BetterTouchTool?

Tags: microphone, applescript, mute

In BetterTouchTool, I made a simple mute widget. The provided code (down below) works perfectly fine, but now I want to have the touchbar button change to its alternate colour and icon when the mic is muted. The widget opens an AppleScript with the following code:

if input volume of (get volume settings) = 0 then
    set level to 100 -- restore volume
    display notification "on" with title "Mic"
else
    set level to 0 -- mute volume
    display notification "off" with title "Mic"
end if

set volume input volume level

return input volume of (get volume settings)

[mute widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9pw3.png)

[mute widget (advanced options)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrP1e.png)

[mute mic icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuHkZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just enter `0` in `Activate alternate color and icon if result matches regex`. BTT will pick up alternate icon when returned value is 0 (muted in this case).

Comment: This didn't work for me at all, what am I doing wrong?